# textarea background color is different than body (slightly dull)

Tags: html, css

I am generating a pdf from html , in which i am using a textarea.
On print preview everything looks fine but on print textarea is slighlty dull

Here is html code

```
textarea{
    text-align:center;
    width:90%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20.9pt;
    letter-spacing:0.252em;
    margin-top:-7px;
    resize:none;
    border:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.63;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    }

<body 
style=
"background:#000;
color:#fff;
text-align:center ;
font-family: sans-serif ;
line-height:29.5pt;
position:absolute;  
margin:85px; 
letter-spacing:0.262em;
line-height: 1.63; 
text-transform: uppercase;
">

 <textarea rows="2">The night the stars smiled and your adventure began</textarea>
```

Here is the print (check long text)

[image]

The rectangular box behind that text is the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the background for `textarea` in `rgba` with alpha `0` like

```
textarea{
    text-align:center;
    width:90%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20.9pt;
    letter-spacing:0.252em;
    margin-top:-7px;
    resize:none;
    border:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.63;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color:#fff;
}
```

So that its background becomes transparent and takes it from body.